# Configure PostgreSQL Query Planner to Prefer Bitmap Scan

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have a table with 25m records that I wish to filter on an indexed column by 10-100 values.

A simple hard coded example with 3 values is as follows:

`select * from my_table where my_column in ('A', 'B', 'C')`

Postgres correctly uses a Bitmap Index Scan and this query is very fast.

These values are dynamic, and I prefer to have them in a temporary table.

If I create a temporary table named cons (or use a CTE) with the values of 'A', 'B' and 'C', and then do the following.

`select my_table.* from my_table join cons using(my_column)`

PostgreSQL does a Sequential Scan of the 25m row table.

It seems that a bitmap scan is the 3rd option the planner picks.

If I run set enable_seqscan = off, then the planner does a merge join/Index Scan (yuck).

If I turn off both of these:

```
set enable_seqscan = off;
set enable_indexscan = off;
```

The the planner correctly chooses the bitmap scan and the query goes from 30s to 200ms.

This is a very common kind of query in my application. I would like to tune the planner in a way to make it prefer the bitmap scans based on these kinds of joins (huge left table, small right table). *Is this possible? If so, how?*

I tried all different kinds of ways of writing the query using sub-queries and the like, but the planner would always pick the sequential scan. I would also put indexes on the temp table to no avail.

I also thought it might be a datatype problem, so I double checked that. The datatype of the columns is varchar(8). The query explain has a cast of ::text for both values. I couldn't tell if this was causing a problem or not (though I don't think so).

My last attempt was to make some convoluted code turn the temp table values into an array and then use the IN or = ANY operators to check, but the planner still picked sequential scan!

If I can't figure out how to make PostgreSQL use a bitmap scan, my last resort will be to do dynamic SQL and build a huge literal list of values to pass in which I'm trying hard not to do.

EDIT:

To show an example of the behavior. I discovered something interesting. If I make a temporary table and only put in 3 records, PostgreSQL it does the bitmap scan. If I put in 4 records, it switches to the index scan. I suspect that somewhere between 5 and 11 it switches to sequential.

Here is an analyze explain of the temp table having 3 values in the temp table.

```
create temp table sbounce (cat_no varchar(8) primary key);
insert into sbounce values
 ('10'), ('11'), ('12');
 ;

CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
ANALYZE

explain analyze
select max(process_timestamp)
from bounce
join sbounce using(cat_no);

                                                                 QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=497698.77..497698.78 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=10.650..10.652 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=573.49..497314.53 rows=153696 width=8) (actual time=9.197..10.601 rows=492 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on sbounce  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=6) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=3 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on bounce  (cost=573.49..165258.85 rows=51232 width=14) (actual time=3.067..3.508 rows=164 loops=3)
               Recheck Cond: ((cat_no)::text = (sbounce.cat_no)::text)
               Heap Blocks: exact=457
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bounce_cat_no  (cost=0.00..560.68 rows=51232 width=0) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=164 loops=3)
                     Index Cond: ((cat_no)::text = (sbounce.cat_no)::text)
 Planning Time: 0.913 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 8
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 1.187 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.661 ms, Emission 8.213 ms, Total 10.061 ms
 Execution Time: 53.134 ms
```

Here is the analyze when there are 4 values in the temp table

```
                                                                         QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=544662.47..544662.48 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=150222.332..150222.380 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Merge Join  (cost=535834.48..544150.15 rows=204928 width=8) (actual time=149780.441..150222.060 rows=492 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: ((hit.cat_no)::text = (sbounce.cat_no)::text)
         ->  Index Scan using hit_cat_no on hit  (cost=0.44..51381086.85 rows=23156868 width=14) (actual time=155.208..150026.353 rows=229309 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=1.08..1.09 rows=4 width=6) (actual time=0.029..0.116 rows=4 loops=1)
               Sort Key: sbounce.cat_no
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               ->  Seq Scan on sbounce  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=6) (actual time=0.013..0.019 rows=4 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 1.565 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 8
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 1.061 ms, Inlining 58.648 ms, Optimization 60.742 ms, Emission 35.399 ms, Total 155.850 ms
 Execution Time: 150269.910 ms
```

Here is another run on 4 records in the temp table with turning off sequential/index scans.

```
                                                                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=10000652003.03..10000652003.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=217.470..217.472 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=10000000573.62..10000651490.71 rows=204928 width=8) (actual time=215.980..217.424 rows=492 loops=1)
         ->  Index Only Scan using sbounce_pkey on sbounce  (cost=10000000000.13..10000000012.19 rows=4 width=6) (actual time=0.015..0.023 rows=4 loops=1)
               Heap Fetches: 4
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on hit  (cost=573.49..162357.31 rows=51232 width=14) (actual time=53.994..54.332 rows=123 loops=4)
               Recheck Cond: ((cat_no)::text = (sbounce.cat_no)::text)
               Heap Blocks: exact=457
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on hit_cat_no  (cost=0.00..560.68 rows=51232 width=0) (actual time=0.042..0.042 rows=123 loops=4)
                     Index Cond: ((cat_no)::text = (sbounce.cat_no)::text)
 Planning Time: 112.191 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 8
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 1.158 ms, Inlining 72.911 ms, Optimization 90.665 ms, Emission 51.906 ms, Total 216.641 ms
 Execution Time: 270.140 ms
```

Comment: Without the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the actual query(along with the query) this is not going to get far.

Comment: details added to question.

Comment: Have "hit" and/or "bounce" been ANALYZED?

Comment: The bitmap index scan is expected to return over 300 times more rows than it actually does.  That makes it appear unfavorable.

Comment: Yes, everything is analyzed. I actually think I came across the problem in that not enough memory was allocated in the postgresql.conf. Increasing the shared buffers and working mem made the planner use the bitmap and indexed scans more appropriately. I would assume that it detected there wasn't enough usable memory to load the bitmap/index into memory? Not sure.